# What to do with previous EFI partition during new installation?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, grub-efi

I have a laptop which came with Ubuntu 14.04 installed. I want to upgrade it to 15.10.
But there is a EFI partition of size 200 MB in it.

There are total 4 partitions -

- EFI
- Ubuntu
- This is where I keep files
- swap

  1. Is it safe to remove the EFI partition during installation and simply install over the existing Ubuntu partition?
  2. Why is the partition there? What is its use?
  3. If it is not safe to remove it, then how to configure it during new installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First** off, I'll answer your second question, "Why is the partition there? What is it's use?"

The EFI partition is created to store EFI-mode boot loaders and related files.

The [Extensible Firmware Interface (EFI) or its version 2.x variant, Unified EFI (UEFI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uefi) is a firmware type that is widespread on recent computers, especially those more recent than 2010. ([Source, Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI))

As for why it's there, it was most likely created when Ubuntu was installed, as most systems have EUFI mode enabled by default.

---

**Second**, "Is it safe to remove the EFI partition during installation?"

Yes and no. If you have Windows installed in UEFI mode then you should probably keep it, as they are in UEFI mode by default and you can't mix UEFI and BIOS/legacy installations.

However, if Ubuntu is your only OS, then you should be able to disable UEFI mode and only work in BIOS version, which may have better support.

---

**Third**, "If it is not safe to remove it, then how to configure it during new installation."

[If you follow the instructions here on the Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#General_principles), then the installer should take care of it just fine, assuming you're doing a fresh install and using the automatic installer.

To sum up what that link is saying, you'll need to:

- Use a 64 bit version of Ubuntu (32bit *can* work, but it's very complicated.)
- You'll also need to [disable QuickBoot/FastBoot](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12397979&postcount=9) and [Intel Smart Response Technology (SRT)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12460938&postcount=6), and if on Windows 8 or newer, you'll need to [disable Fast Startup](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html).
- Use a supported version of Ubuntu. Support for UEFI was added in 11.10, but more recent versions are far more reliable. 12.04 or greater is preferred.

If you're planning on doing custom partitioning, then it will be a bit more complicated, as you'll have to manually create a UEFI partition and configure Ubuntu to mount it at `/boot/efi`.

Answer (score 1):

Your efi partition is part of efi boot

If Ubuntu is your only OS, you do not need it, but you will need to configure your bios to disable efi boot (ie configure legacy boot)

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: It is EFI , not UEFI. Would you please answer the questions one by one?

Comment: It is the ESP - efi system partition which is used by the Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition If you want to boot in UEFI boot mode, which your hard ware must be if it has an ESP already, then you will need an ESP. You can delete it, but it will just be recreated. Or it will be reused. Or you convert to the 35 year old MBR partitioning and BIOS boot.

Comment: UEFI is just EFI version 2.x. AFAIK, the only computers that currently ship with EFI 1.x are Apple Macs; every current PC I'm aware of uses EFI 2.x (aka UEFI). Some terminology, such as *EFI* System Partition (ESP), continues to use the "EFI" term even when the firmware is UEFI. As EFI 1.x still exists, "EFI" is the more generic term, and some people (myself included) use it in preference to "UEFI" except where the distinction is important.